# accessing the attribute of a python object depending on a second attibute of that object

Tags: python, class, oop, dictionary, attributes

I would like to find the second attribute of objects in a class such that the first attribute has a certain value.

```
Class Day(object):
    def __init__(self, a_datetime_date):
        self.date = a_datetime_date
        self.colour = None
```

I now instantiate a whole lot of objects in a loop:

```
for x in a_list_of_dates:
    some_day = Day(x)
    some_day.colour = 'Red' # or some other values depending on the details
```

Being quite new to objects, I just saved them in a dict.  `{'1': <__main__.Day object at 0x7f9a444cacd0>, '2': <__main__.Day object at 0x7f9a447cacd0>, etc}`

Now is there a simple way for me to retrieve the `colour` corresponding to a range of dates?  Or perhaps, more simply to a single date?

I can only think of doing something like `sorted(dict.iteritems())`, and then going one by one through the list checking `day_object.date`. If it's the date I want, then using `day_object.colour` to find about the colour.

The answer to the question may come in two forms:

1. A better way to store/access a few hundred objects (other than a dict)
2. A way to query the objects in the dict to get the colours of the days I'm interested in.

Thank you.

**Edit:** In simplifying a little the question, my motivation for using classes was lost.  The "Day" object actually has 15 attributes and 2 methods (not just `colour`). So @*cole*'s suggestion is good, but not for so many attributes.  The objects are used to count various things:  How many of the 300 days are breaks? how many are half days? Perhaps I'm stuck between using a complex list/dict and moving to a full ORM?

Comment: It almost sounds like you want a ORM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use `bisect` and `OrderedDict`.

```
import bisect
from collections import OrderedDict

def foo(date):
    day = Day(date)
    day.colour = 'Red' # or some other values depending on the details
    return day

container = OrderDict({date: foo(date) for date in sorted(date_list)})

keys = list(container.keys())

# find by range of dates

start_index = bisect.bisect_left(keys, start_date)
end_index = bisect.bisect(keys, end_date)

for index in range(start_index, end_index);
    print(container[keys[index]].colour)

# find by a single date

print(container[single_date].colour)
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, a list is a better data structure for what you want to do. Unless the keys have some meaning that isn't obvious from the question.

You can do what you want with a list comprehension (once everything is in a list).

```
foo = list()
for date in dates:
    some_day = Day(date)
    some_day.colour = 'Red'
    foo.append(some_day)

values = [x.colour for x in foo if date_1 <= x.date <= date_2]
```

Comment: Here's more context on the code (https://gist.github.com/alphydan/bd3d5cf1b7b6acf3b76f818c73b5965f ). I simplified the keys here to try to keep it simple.  A list of nested lists would be the alternative then?

Comment: Unfortunately it also depends on another 3 or 4 attributes.  I simplified the class here but it has to be between those dates, not be a holiday, not be a half-day, not be a study-leave day, not a weekend ... and then find the "colour" and the number of the day, etc.  So the principle is the same, but depends on many attributes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what else you're planning to do with this besides look for colour.  Try using a color hashed dictionary; this will keep create a relationship between color and day:

```
from collections import defaultdict
color_dict = defaultdict(list)

for x in a_list_of_dates:
    some_day = Day(x)
    some_day.colour = 'Red' # Not sure how you're planning to make these assignments.
    colour_dict['Red'].append(some_day)

# Look up all Day objects colored Red
colour_dict['Red']
```

**In re**: "A way to query the objects in the dict to get the colours of the days I'm interested in."
If you want to go with the current dictionary data structure -- I wouldn't recommend :) :

```
[day for day in dict_of_days.values if day.colour='Red']
```

But you'll notice that your keys don't have much meaning or utility in this form so I'd recommend storing this in a list instead of a dict.  Once in a list you can run the following to get all days that are colored red:

```
[day for day in list_of_days if day.colour='Red']
```

**Alternate solutions**:

1. Store your data in a **pandas dataframe**.  http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html.  This way you can slice and dice the data in a tabular format (i.e. columns= [Day, Colour, IsHalfDay, etc.])
2. For a quick lightweight ORM solution try the one-to-many (color-to-day) or many-to-many (color-to-day) relationship http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you sure you don't want an array? Either data structure should handle a few hundred objects with ease, but it makes more sense to me to use an array here.
2. I'd use `filter`

`filter(lambda day: min_date < day.date < max_date, array_of_dates)`

Note that this is assuming you have an array of dates.

---

After writing that the thought came to me: why not do away with the object entirely and just have a dict with the key being a datetime object and the value being the color? You'd still have to `filter` to get a range, though (it ought to be faster than sorting at least).

Comment: this makes sense, rereading my question.  See comment above for more details on the actual complexity of the problem.

Comment: I'd go with @stamaimer's solution myself. Ordered dicts seem more reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you shouldn't be using a class here if what you want is a dict.  There's a [good video about this on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9pEzgHorH0).  It's much easier to work with a list of dicts than a list of classes.  You could even have one dict with each key being the date if it's going to be unique for each of them.

When you say you 'saved them in a dict' what do you mean?  You made a copy of each class as a dict with each having a numerical key?  That's a waste of memory and CPU time.